# Convert an integer array into a type vx_array (Related to OpenVX), and conversely print the integer elements of the vx_array in C++ OpenVX framework

Tags: c++, embedded, openvx

What I am trying is to convert a structure object into an OpenVX array and then conversly extract and print the elements of OpenVx array to verify.

Perhaps this a dummy structure which called Bounding box which has 4 co ordiantes of type float.

```
typedef struct _FloatRectangle_T
{
    float32_t fStartX = 0.f;
    float32_t fStartY = 0.f;
    float32_t fEndX = 0.f;
    float32_t fEndY = 0.f;
} FloatRectangle_T;

typedef struct _BoundingBoxData_T
{
    FloatRectangle_T rec;
    float conf = 0.f;
} BoundingBoxData_T;
```

I wanted to convert the object of the below type into a vx array.

```
BoundingBoxData_T bboxData;
bboxData[index].rec.fStartX = 100;
bboxData[index].rec.fStartY = 200;
bboxData[index].rec.fEndX = 300;
bboxData[index].rec.fEndY = 400;
bboxData[i].conf = 1.0f;
```

Now I am assuming the below is a vague representation of covnerting structure object
into vx array.

```
m_vxContext = vxCreateContext();
e_vxBB = vxRegisterUserStruct(m_vxContext, sizeof(BoundingBoxData_T));
m_vxBB = vxCreateArray(m_vxContext, e_vxBB, 10);
vxFaceBB = vxAddArrayItems(m_vxBB, 1, Bbox, sizeof(BoundingBoxData_T));
```

Also please guide on how to extract the elements from vx_array vxFaceBB and print it.

Comment: I might have wrongly created vx_array please create best known to you

Comment: See that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: C++ doesn't need typedef with struct.